# Horizontal Single Bar Graph with Two color representation

Tags: android, animation, svg, imageview, bar-chart

What is the easiest way to create a horizontal single bar Graph in Android with two colors representations? 
something like this[image]

The amount 64% could obviously get increased up to 100% timely manner (animation??? :( )
is it SVG or Image Views or how?

Answer (score 0):

This layout achieves above, adjust p3 TextView width (red background) in code as percentage of p1 TextView width (blue background) changing p4 TextView text to the current percentage (consider what to do as percentage reaches 100% as labels will overlap, suggest setting text value on p3 after a certain limit, say 85%, and then hiding p4. I suggest using AsyncTask (or other threading method) if increasing percentage incrementally to see UI updates. Also look at Android Tween Animation.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">  
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="#FF000000" />
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/p1"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF00FFFF" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/p2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/p1"
        android:text="100%" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/p3"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFF0000"
        android:gravity="end"  />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/p4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/p3"
        android:text="64%" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```